# Select collection view cell on load - Custom UICollectionView class

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a custom collection view (`tabBarCollectionView`), which should load with the first cell being selected, as per the code below. However, this is not working. I know this as the cell should be a different colour when selected, but isn't.

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    tabBarCollectionView.register(TabBarCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)

    addSubview(tabBarCollectionView)
    tabBarCollectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|[v0]|", views: tabBarCollectionView)
    addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|[v0]|", views: tabBarCollectionView)

    tabBarCollectionView.selectItem(at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0), animated: false, scrollPosition: [])
}
```

Full code of custom `UIView` class is inserted below:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class TabBar: UIView, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
let imageNames = ["homeIcon", "exploreIcon", "addIcon", "inboxIcon", "profileIcon"]

lazy var tabBarCollectionView: UICollectionView = {

    // All collection view implementations in here

    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)

    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self

    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    return collectionView
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    tabBarCollectionView.register(TabBarCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)

    addSubview(tabBarCollectionView)
    tabBarCollectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|[v0]|", views: tabBarCollectionView)
    addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|[v0]|", views: tabBarCollectionView)

    self.tabBarCollectionView.allowsSelection = true
    self.tabBarCollectionView.selectItem(at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0), animated: false, scrollPosition: [])
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    tabBarCollectionView.allowsSelection = true
    tabBarCollectionView.selectItem(at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0), animated: false, scrollPosition: [])
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! TabBarCell

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    cell.tabBarImageView.image = UIImage(named: imageNames[indexPath.item])?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    cell.tabBarImageView.tintColor = UIColor.pinpointGrey

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    return CGSize(width: frame.width / 5, height: frame.height)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    return 0
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}



}

class TabBarCell: UICollectionViewCell {

let tabBarImageView: UIImageView = {

    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "homeIcon")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    imageView.tintColor = UIColor.pinpointGrey
    return imageView
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    setupViews()
}

func setupViews() {

    backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    addSubview(tabBarImageView)
    addConstraintsWithFormat("H:[v0(42)]", views: tabBarImageView)
    addConstraintsWithFormat("V:[v0(42)]", views: tabBarImageView)

    addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: tabBarImageView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: tabBarImageView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
}

override var isHighlighted: Bool {

    didSet {
        if tabBarImageView.isHighlighted == true {
            self.tabBarImageView.tintColor = UIColor.pinpointBlue
        } else {
            self.tabBarImageView.tintColor = UIColor.pinpointGrey
        }
    }
}

override var isSelected: Bool {

    didSet {
        tabBarImageView.tintColor = isSelected ? UIColor.pinpointBlue : UIColor.pinpointGrey
    }
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

Comment: `tabBarCollectionView.allowsSelection = true` that would allow the cell to be selected. For doing anything meaningful copy your code from `didSelectItemAt:`

Comment: try to do it in `layoutSubViews`

Comment: or do this selection in the owner VC's viewWillAppear.

Comment: @user1046037 @KTang I added `tabBarCollectionView.allowsSelection = true`, but it's not in a `UICollectionViewController` class, but in a `UIView` and `UICollectionView` class

Answer (score 0):

Where is your datasource set? Do you load it separately and then do a reloadData()?

If yes, then you should select the cell then and not during your viewDidLoad method as during load the collection view might not have been populated yet.

You could also add to a viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear method as this gets called after the collection view has been populated

Comment: This has been loaded in its own UIView and UICollectionView class, so I don't have these methods.

Comment: have you tried adding `tabBarCollectionView.selectItem(at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0), animated: false, scrollPosition: [])` to viewDidAppear?

Comment: There is no `viewDidAppear` since its not a `UICollectionViewController` class, it's a `UICollectionView` class instead

Comment: then try adding to layoutSubview()

Comment: I added `override func layoutSubviews() {
        tabBarCollectionView.allowsSelection = true
        tabBarCollectionView.selectItem(at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0), animated: false, scrollPosition: [])
    }`

Comment: Also added `super.layoutSubviews()` to the func

Comment: can you copy/paste more of your code in to your question? just this amount of code is very hard to see how you put everything together. Try to put more details of what classes you implemented, what files is the code in, etc....

Comment: All of it now :)

Comment: Code is added to the question :)